# I am trying to hide my main menu screens widgets when i select a submenu

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, hide

now the issue is that i am being left with a blank screen and my other widget are not being displayed

```
def hotfood():
    shclogo.grid_forget()
    maintitle1.grid_forget()
    maintitle2.grid_forget()
    hf.grid_forget()
    cf.grid_forget()
    frzn.grid_forget()
    drnks.grid_forget()
    snks.grid_forget()
    crt.grid_forget()
    hotfoodhome = Button(hotfood, text = 'Home', bg = 'white', fg = 
    'black', font = 'arial 20 bold')
    hotfoodhome.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = EW)
    hotfoodtitle = Label (hotfood, text = 'HOT FOOD', bg = 'white', fg = 
    'black', font = 'arial 48 bold')
    hotfoodtitle.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = EW)
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] — i.e. more complete code.

Comment: if you used `grid()` to display then use `grid_forget()` to hide. To show something in the same window  don't create new one - `Tk()` - but use variable in which you have current  window - ie. `current_window.title("HOT FOOD")`, etc.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly but now it is removing all my widgets but not replacing them with what i want and leaving a blank screen. I have updated the code now with the new issue